# Can I get custom Minecraft skins on Xbox using a hard drive?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I want my own Minecraft custom skin. I am on Minecraft Bedrock Edition btw.
If I download a skin from a website such as, https://www.planetminecraft.com/ and add it to my hard drive, will I be able to add it to add it to my Xbox and add it to Minecraft?
Im not sure if there is a specific folder I have to add the skin into for it to work.
If there is, please let me know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way to get custom addons on console too. Do you know how to do that? If so, can you use a `.mcpack` that's a skin pack to do the same with skins?

Comment: the MCpack skin thing doesnt work on xbox

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add custom skins to xbox, you must use the ingame skin creator.